# how to put active class on page location with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add active classes on on my navigation menu so there is a border and the writting is coloured for the specific page your on but it isn't working. It worked for the primary navigation but wont work for my secondary one any ideas as to why its not working would be appreciated thank you? my code is down below. the active class at the bottom is what should be applied

```js
const currentLocations = location.href;
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.secondary a');
const menuLengths = menuItems.length
for (let i = 0; i < menuLengths; i++) {
  if (menuItems[i].href === currentLocations) {
    menuItems[i].className = "active"
  }
}
```

```css
.secondarynav-item-trading {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 15px 5px;
  width: 1430px;
  top: 13px;
  left: 30px;
}

.secondarynav-item-trading a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 190px;
}

.secondarynavigation-item-trading ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.secondarynavigation-item-trading li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.secondarynavigation-item-trading a:hover {
  color: #fd886b;
  border: 1px solid #fd886b;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.secondarynavigation-item-trading a:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.secondarynav-item-trading ::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.secondarynavigation-item-trading a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #fd886b;
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.secondary a.active {
  color: #fd886b;
  border: 1px solid #fd886b;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header class="secondarynav-messages">
  <div class="secondary">
    <!-- secondary navigation for homepage -->
    <nav alt="secondarynavigation-messages" id="secondarynavigation-messages">
      <!-- secondary navigation buttons below the main navigation -->
      <ul class="secondarynavigation-messages" id="secondarynavigation-messages">
        <li><a href="messages-inbox.php" id="inbox-active" class="inbox-active">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="messages-sent.php" class="sent-active">Sent</a></li>
        <li><a href="messages-compose-a-message.php">Compose a message</a></li>
        <li><a href="messages-drafts.php" class="drafts-active">Drafts</a></li>
        <li><a href="messages-archived.php" class="archived-active">Archived</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

the way I have it in the code above is working for the first page but none of the others but I have done the exact same thing in the primary nav and it worked i also copied the code on a new website document and it worked but for some reason its not working here

Comment: Are you including the JavaScript file and CSS stylesheets on the other pages? I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work if both `.js` and `.css` files that are on the first page are also on the other pages. If you add the `active` class to elements from the first page through JavaScript those elements will still have the `<a class"active">` declaration when you arrive at the second page.

Comment: yeah they are required through php i dont get why its not working either